# Scala Aggregate Projection

Tags: scala, aggregate-functions

How can I project / transform the following

```
List(("A", 1.0), ("A", 3.0), ("B", 2.0), ("B", 2.0))
```

to

```
List(("A", 4.0),("B", 4.0))
```

So I aggregate by the string and sum the doubles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val x = List(("A", 1.0), ("A", 3.0), ("B", 2.0), ("B", 2.0))
val y = x.groupBy(_._1).map { case (a,bs) => a -> bs.map(_._2).sum }
y.toList  // List((A,4.0), (B,4.0))
```

Comment: 25k rep; you should know not to post a code-only answer.

Comment: mapValues would make it slightly shorter and maybe a bit clearer : `x.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)`

Comment: @Didier, The `mapValues` method does not work like `map`.  It creates a *view* of a map, meaning that every time a value is accessed, it would have to recompute the `.map(_._2).sum`.

Comment: @dhg Indeed so says the doc (not prominently enough in my view) and so the source confirms. Thanks, I never knew that.